# Can not click components inside a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, click

I'm trying to create a View with ScrollView, programmatically, because I need some more complex treatments that Storyboard does not allow me to do.

The problem is that the components inserted in ScrollView do not capture the taps. Already test on physical devices and also on the emulator.

**The UIScrollView is not in full screen.** There is a View with buttons fixed at the bottom.

**Note:** I'm setting the constraints with the [PureLayout](https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout) library. I can switch to the Apple constraint library if it is better.

Here, my View:

```
import UIKit
import PureLayout

class DetalheProduto: UIView {
var shouldSetupConstraints = true

let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds

var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var viewFundo: UIView!

var bannerView: UIImageView!
var viewPreco: UIView!
var preco: UILabel!

var fundo: UIView!

var nomeProduto: UILabel!
var divisor : UIView!

var lblQuantidade: UILabel!
var stepperQuantidade: UIStepperCustom!


var viewAvancar: UIView!
var divisor2: UIView!
var lblTotal: UILabel!
var total: UILabel!
var btnAvancar: UIButton!


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: .zero)

    self.addSubview(scrollView)

    viewFundo = UIView(frame:  .zero)

    self.scrollView.addSubview(viewFundo)

    bannerView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
    bannerView.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: screenSize.width / 2)
    bannerView.autoSetDimension(.width, toSize: screenSize.width)
    bannerView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    self.viewFundo.addSubview(bannerView)

    viewPreco = UIView(frame: .zero)
    viewPreco.backgroundColor = UIColor(codHex: 0x6BC43C)
    viewPreco.addShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1), radius: 2.0, color: UIColor.black, opacity: 0.5)

    self.viewFundo.addSubview(viewPreco)

    preco = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    preco.text = "R$ 0,00"
    preco.textAlignment = .center
    preco.textColor = UIColor.white
    preco.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)

    viewPreco.addSubview(preco)

    fundo = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    fundo.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    fundo.autoSetDimension(.width, toSize: screenSize.width)

    self.viewFundo.addSubview(fundo)

    ///

    nomeProduto = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    nomeProduto.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: 32.0)
    nomeProduto.text = "Nome do Produto"
    nomeProduto.textColor = UIColor.orange
    nomeProduto.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)

    self.fundo.addSubview(nomeProduto)

    divisor = UIView(frame: .zero)
    divisor.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: 1.0)
    divisor.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    self.fundo.addSubview(divisor)

    lblQuantidade = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    lblQuantidade.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: 30.0)
    lblQuantidade.text = "Quantidade"
    lblQuantidade.textColor = UIColor(codHex: 0x707070)
    lblQuantidade.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)

    self.fundo.addSubview(lblQuantidade)

    stepperQuantidade = UIStepperCustom(frame: .zero)
    stepperQuantidade.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: 30.0)
    stepperQuantidade.autoSetDimension(.width, toSize: 120.0)
    stepperQuantidade.borderColorBotaoDireito = UIColor.orange
    stepperQuantidade.textColorBotaoDireito = UIColor.orange
    stepperQuantidade.valor = 1
    stepperQuantidade.valorPasso = 1
    stepperQuantidade.valorMinimo = 1
    stepperQuantidade.valorMaximo = 100

    self.fundo.addSubview(stepperQuantidade)



    viewAvancar = UIView(frame: .zero)
    viewAvancar.autoSetDimension(.width, toSize: screenSize.width)
    viewAvancar.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: 86.0)
    viewAvancar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    self.addSubview(viewAvancar)

    divisor2 = UIView(frame: .zero)
    divisor2.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: 1.0)
    divisor2.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    self.viewAvancar.addSubview(divisor2)

    lblTotal = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    lblTotal.text = "TOTAL:"
    lblTotal.textColor = UIColor(codHex: 0x6BC43C)
    lblTotal.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)

    self.viewAvancar.addSubview(lblTotal)

    total = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    total.text = "R$ 0,00"
    total.textAlignment = .right
    total.textColor = UIColor(codHex: 0x6BC43C)
    total.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)

    self.viewAvancar.addSubview(total)

    btnAvancar = UIButton(frame: .zero)
    btnAvancar.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: 45.0)
    btnAvancar.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    btnAvancar.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    btnAvancar.setTitle("ADICIONAR AO CARRINHO", for: .normal)

    self.viewAvancar.addSubview(btnAvancar)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func updateConstraints() {
    if(shouldSetupConstraints) {

        let zero: CGFloat = 0.0
        let margem: CGFloat = 8.0
        let margem2x: CGFloat = 16.0

        scrollView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges(with: .zero, excludingEdge: .bottom)
        scrollView.autoPinEdge(.bottom, to: .top, of: viewAvancar, withOffset: zero)

        viewFundo.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges()

        bannerView.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .top)

        viewPreco.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewMargin: .right)
        viewPreco.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewMargin: .top)

        preco.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewMargins()

        fundo.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .left)
        fundo.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .right)
        fundo.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: bannerView, withOffset: zero)

        nomeProduto.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges(with: UIEdgeInsets(inset: margem), excludingEdge: .bottom)

        divisor.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewMargin: .left)
        divisor.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewMargin: .right)
        divisor.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: nomeProduto, withOffset: margem)

        if (lblQuantidade != nil && lblQuantidade.superview != nil) {
            lblQuantidade.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewMargin: .left)
            lblQuantidade.autoPinEdge(.right, to: .left, of: stepperQuantidade, withOffset: margem)
            lblQuantidade.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: divisor, withOffset: margem2x)
        }


        stepperQuantidade.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewMargin: .right)
        stepperQuantidade.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: divisor, withOffset: margem2x)


        viewAvancar.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges(with: UIEdgeInsets.zero, excludingEdge: .top)

        divisor2.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .left)
        divisor2.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .right)
        divisor2.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .top)

        lblTotal.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: divisor2, withOffset: margem)
        lblTotal.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewMargin: .left)

        total.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: divisor2, withOffset: margem)
        total.autoPinEdge(.left, to: .right, of: lblTotal, withOffset: margem)
        total.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewMargin: .right)

        btnAvancar.autoPinEdges(toSuperviewMarginsExcludingEdge: .top)
        btnAvancar.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: total, withOffset: margem)
        btnAvancar.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: lblTotal, withOffset: margem)

        //

        shouldSetupConstraints = false
    }
    super.updateConstraints()
}
}
```

ViewTree:

```
UIView
-UIScrollView
..-UIView
...-UILabel
...-UIView
...
-UIView
..-UIView
..-UILabel
..-UILabel
..-UIButton
```

And Controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Detalhes"
    self.view.addSubview(det)
    det.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges(with: UIEdgeInsets.zero)

    det.nomeProduto.text = produto.nome

    Utilities.smartLoadImage(path: produto.getSrcImagem(), img: det.bannerView)

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    var sizeOfContent: CGFloat = 0

    for i in 0..<det.fundo.subviews.count {
        sizeOfContent += det.fundo.subviews[i].bounds.height
    }


    det.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: det.screenSize.width, height: (sizeOfContent + det.bannerView.bounds.height))


}
```

---

How can I solve this?

@EDIT:

> Probably you contentSize is not adjusted to your scrollView size. Print them and you will see what is happening.

In viewDidLayoutSubviews() the size is set to **w = 320.0** and **h = 406.0**. Seems correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

**viewFundo** was not set height and therefore did not accept clicks on components.
I set the size of the **viewFundo** equal to the size of the **ScrollView.contentSize** and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you contentSize is not adjusted to your scrollView size.
Print them and you will see what is happening.

Comment: I'm setting the contentSize in the controller, according to the size of the View it should display. I checked this, and after the viewDidLayoutSubviews() it gets **w = 320.0** and **h = 406.0**

Comment: Other Idea is that you need to check ..maybe you have something on top of the tappable view...otherwise I have no Idea.

Comment: Yeah, I also think that must be it, but I could not identify anything.